# Better to lump everything together under m/v/c folders or seperate module folders with m,v,c files?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, flask, directory-structure

In this wiki (https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/wiki/Large-app-how-to), the creator of flask (or whomever wrote the wiki) recommends the directory structure of seperate module folders with model, view, controller files under it. Most other places I see a models, view, controller, form folder and all the modules are lumped together under them. Is there a good reason to choose one way over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it depends on the app's size.

- For small to tiny apps you can have one flat package or even a single file.
- If your app is medium-sized, one level of grouping (models, views, forms) will do.
- If the app is going to be larger, two levels are better. If the modules of the app are tightly interconnected, then maybe you can split first into model/view, then by module, but usually modularization is all about making them independent, so it's logical to split by module, then, for large modules, into model/view.